# Sending props to Child Component when there's a change in state of parent Component, the state of child component is always one behind

Tags: reactjs

This is code for a Parent Component. That has a button and contains a Child Component too.

My question is: Will React be able to send the `prop` when the value of the `state` changes? If not, then what do I need to do to send the prop when the change of state happens?

- Although the component will re-render after the state changes, but I had to click the button twice to see a change in the text.

**How do I make it happen in sync with the change of state in the parent component?**

Code for Parent Component:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                toBeDrafted: false
            };
            this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
        }

        handleButtonClick() {
            this.setState({
                toBeDrafted: true
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
                    <ChildComponent valueOfButton={this.state.toBeDrafted} />
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the Child Component

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            toBeUpdated: false
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        if (this.props.valueOfButton === true) {
            this.setState({
                toBeUpdated: !this.state.toBeUpdated
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p>
                    The Button has been
                    {
                        this.state.toBeUpdated === true
                        ? "clicked"
                        : "not clicked"
                    }
                </p>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes wher you setState react rerender the component and its children passing the children the new props.

Comment: Can we define button in child? That would solve your problem

Comment: Yes you can define the button on the child. and pass the handleButtonClick as props to the child component so when the button is clicked on the child call the handler on the parent. @NikhilPathania

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we click on Click me button `handleButtonClick()` is called which inside it calls `setState()`

On this call the page is re-rendered. This caused value of props passed to child component to change. So when you change the state of parent using `setState` props passed to child component are also changed.

Update to your updated question:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
   this.setState({
      toBeUpdated: !this.state.toBeUpdated
    });
  }
```

Remove the if condition because it is the one causing issue and props are updated properly

Comment: yes, but I want it to be reflected immediately. Instead, on the first click, it sends false and I don't want that behavior. How do I correct that?

Comment: I checked, its working on first click, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should not use componentWillRecieveProps as it is legacy and cause problems.
check the docs: [componentWillRecieveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)